# tikzposter + tikzscale not working?

Tags: tikzposter, tikzscale

I've started creating a poster with `tikzposter` and have run into troubles when trying to use `tikzscale`. Namely, although the `.log`-file tells me

> `Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:`
>
> `(grfext)              [.tikz,.TIKZ,.TikZ,.pgf,.PGF,.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,
>   .jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]`

I get a `LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .tikz.` when trying to use `\includegraphics` with a `.tikz`-file. The following MWE is based directly on the template that comes with the package; I've only added the packages, a sample `.tikz`-file and the content of the first block.

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}% if really necessary

\begin{filecontents}{square.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-10,-10) rectangle (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{tikzposter} %Options for format can be included here    
\usepackage{tikzscale}

% Title, Author, Institute
\title{Template Poster}
\author{Author(s)}
\institute{Institute}
\titlegraphic{LogoGraphic Inserted Here}

%Choose Layout
\usetheme{Default}

\begin{document}

% Title block with title, author, logo, etc.
\maketitle
\block{Basic Block}{%
\begin{tikzfigure}[Caption]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{square.tikz}
\end{tikzfigure}
}
\begin{columns}

% FIRST column
\column{0.6}% Width set relative to text width

\block{Large Column}{Text\\Text\\Text Text Text}
\note{Note with default behavior}
\note[targetoffsetx=12cm, targetoffsety=-1cm, angle=20, rotate=25]
{Note \\ offset and rotated}

% First column - second block
\block{Block titles with enough text will automatically obey spacing requirements }
{Text\\Text}

% First column - third block
\block{Sample Block 4}{T\\E\\S\\T}

% SECOND column
\column{0.4}
%Second column with first block's top edge aligned with with previous column's top.

% Second column - first block
\block[titleleft]{Smaller Column}{Test}

% Second column - second block
\block[titlewidthscale=0.6, bodywidthscale=0.8]
{Variable width title}{Block with smaller width.}

% Second column - third block
\block{}{Block with no title}

% Second column - A collection of blocks in subcolumn environment.
\begin{subcolumns}
\subcolumn{0.27} \block{1}{First block.} \block{2}{Second block}
\subcolumn{0.4} \block{Sub-columns}{Sample subblocks\\Second subcolumn}
\subcolumn{0.33} \block{4}{Fourth} \block{}{Final Subcolumn block}
\end{subcolumns}

% Bottomblock
\block{Final Block in column}{
Sample block.
}
\end{columns}
\block[titleleft, titleoffsetx=2em, titleoffsety=1em, bodyoffsetx=2em,%
bodyoffsety=-2cm, roundedcorners=10, linewidth=0mm, titlewidthscale=0.7,%
bodywidthscale=0.9, bodyverticalshift=2cm, titleright]
{Block outside of Columns}{Along with several options enabled}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `tikzscale` work with nested `tikzpicture`s? Because that's essentially what you'd need it to do here. The poster is basically a `tikzpicture` and then you are putting another inside it. In general, nesting `tikzpictures` is bad and does weird things in some cases, though sometimes it works and cannot be avoided. But maybe this is one of those cases where it screws things up?